# problema al usar ckeditor con jquery

Tags: ckeditor

Estoy usando *`ckeditor`* (en un proyecto en mvc c# visual studio 2013), para hacer un editor de texto, uso `jquery` para mostrar el texto guardado en la base de datos, el problema es que cuando visualizo el editor en un computador portátil se ve bien, pero en un computador de pantalla grande (un todo en uno por ejemplo) el texto no se ve.

*Imagen 1:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo alojado un sitio en un servidor, entonces si veo el editor *(el texto que guardé)* desde un portátil se ve bien, pero en un computador de pantalla grande entonces no se puede ver el texto que guardé en la base de datos:

*Imagen 2:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las imágenes 1 y 2 son, es la forma como se visualiza el mismo editor desde diferentes computadores; en el primero en un portátil y el otro en un pantalla grande.

---

El proceso es el siguiente: ingreso al módulo y pongo información en el editor, hago click en *`guardar`* y el texto se guarda en la base de datos, luego cada que entro al módulo puedo visualizar el texto guardado *(que en este caso es la política de una empresa)* y puedo modificar o eliminar.

Para mostrar el texto en el editor, tengo este código en el controlador, script y vista:

```
public ActionResult CargarPolitica()
    {
        gs = new PoliticaServicios();
        string politica = 
        gs.ObtenerPolitica(SessionDataSG_SST.EmpresaSession.Pk_Id_Empresa);
        if (politica != "")
        {
            return Json(new { success = true, Politica = politica }
            , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Messages = "Ingrese Una Política";
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }          



function ObtenerPolitica() {
    $.ajax({
        url: urlBase + '/Politica/Politicasst/CargarPolitica',
        data: {},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result) {
            if (result) {
                //console.log(result.Politica);
                $idtextareaPolitica.text(result.Politica);
            }
        }
    });
}                                                                                 

<textarea name="strDescripcion_Politica" placeholder="Ingrese por favor la Política de Seguridad y Salud en el Trabajo." cols="7" id="editor1" required></textarea>                                         
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
</script>
```

Comment: Hola Jhony, bienvenido. Puedes mostrar el codigo que tienes? Recuerda visitar el [Tour] y [ask] para aprender más de como funciona este sitio. Un saludo

Comment: ¿De dónde viene el texto que aparece en la primera imagen... es de una url? Puede que no estés visualizando los mismos archivos o que haya un problema de url, pues en la imagen 1 estás desde el localhost y en la imagen 2 estás en una conexion remota. Sería interesante que probases la conexión remota desde el portatil o desde otro portátil. Por otra parte, viendo la url en ambas imágenes, en una aparece el path `Politicas` antes de `Login`, pero en otra no. A ver si no estás cargando dos cosas distintas.

Comment: Me equivoque al poner la imagen1 (esta debia mostrar la misma URL de la imagen 2), alli queria mostrar como se veía el mismo editor desde diferentes computadores. el proyecto esta en un servidor y también lo tengo localmente. respondiendo a la pregunta de Cedano el texto esta almacenado en una base de datos en el servidor. Ya cambié la imagen que puse, como se puede apreciar en las imágenes, el mismo sitio se ve diferente desde un portátil y un pc de pantalla grande (no se puede visualizar el texto).